# Perl: Split string by everything but whitespaces

Tags: regex, perl, split, whitespace, inverse

I want to split a string by everything but whitespaces.

**Example:**

Assume that I have a string:

```
"The    quick  brown fox    jumps over   the lazy dog"
```

I want to split it and get the following list of space-strings:

```
["    ", "  ", " ", "    ", " ", "   ", " ", " "]
```

Can you please show me how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\S` to split by here which means match any non-white space character.

```
my @list = split /\S+/, $string;
```

Or better yet, just match your whitespace instead of having to split.

```
my @list = $string =~ /\s+/g;
```

Comment: This looks to be the best answer, especially since he beat me to the second option, which is probably the best.

Answer (score 1):

`\S` splits on any non-whitespace.
However, if you want to include tabs and newlines, then you should use  (single character space).  More than likely what you want is the `\S` as [hwnd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2206004/hwnd)  has provided.

```
my $string = q{The    quick  brown fox    jumps over   the lazy dog};
my @values = split /[^ ]+/, $string;
```

Comment: It returns empty list

Comment: It shouldn't, but I did forget the repetition `+` operator

Answer (score 0):

why not just look for the spaces instead of splitting by non-space characters?
pattern = `(\s+)` [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uN5jI8)